# Is #include a directory valid in C project?

Tags: c

I'm reusing a code that have the syntax similar to this:

```
#include "..\..\..\directory-name"
```

Normally we include a file but in this case a directory is included.

**Is it a valid syntax and what it will do ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All `#include` does is opens the file, reads the contents, and injects those contents into the *preprocessed* source file in place of the `#include`.

So no, attempting to `#include` a directory makes no sense.

Although it looks syntactically correct, the preprocessor will, in your case, attempt to open `directory-name` as a file.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not valid syntax for c and it will not open any directory file.
This doesn't make any sense in c.